# Inserting Values only if Datediff to the other Value is high enough

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

So I have a Table (1) with Values

- BootNumber
- BootDate

And a Table (2)

- BootID
- BootNumber

---

Now I wanna run a Insert Query over it from Table 1 to Table 2 inserting all Boots into Table(2), the difficult thing is that the field value `BootNumber` can  occur more often, for example the BootNumber `12345` can occur in 2015 and in 2019.

The new data model differenciates those Records via the BootID(2), but I cant get a query going that only imports the Boots if they have 12 months between them and the last record of that boot number in the Table(2).

`BootNumbers with more than 12 months difference in Date should be a new record in Table (2)`

Comment: Whats the DBMS? SQL server or MS Access ? Is the BootID an autonumber? If not how do you generate it ?

Comment: @ThomasG BootID is autonumber, I use MS Access Frontend with linked tables from SQL Server

Comment: Selecting record depends on value in another record. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the list of records you want to insert using [Analytic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
The `LAG` function is a window function. You can create a partition using `OVER` clause. Creating a window partitioned by BootNumber can give you an sorted list of values. Here is an example with your tables:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    BootNumber INT,
    BootDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(12345, '20150101')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(12345, '20150601')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(12345, '20190101')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
        Diff = DATEDIFF(MONTH, LAG(BootDate) OVER (PARTITION BY BootNumber ORDER BY BootDate), BootDate),
        PrevDate = LAG(BootDate) OVER (PARTITION BY BootNumber ORDER BY BootDate) --for debug only
    FROM @Table1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Diff >= 12
```

Because you use linked servers, you should create a procedure on SQL Server and use the procedure's parameters for filtering in your select. The procedure can return you a table like the from CTE. Use this data for your insert in Access.